# How can i split a nswindow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

So I am trying to emulate the new cleanlymac app. It looks like it has two windows on top of each other, one without the traffic lights and the other with it, but they were treated as one. That had the ability for the back one to slip out at the beginning. Would anyone have a good idea of how this was constructed?

Here is a photo of the cleanmymac app:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are actually ONE WINDOW.

You can easily acheive this by using vertical [NSSplitView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSplitView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with 2 panes.

Here you can opt for divider in between or fix the splitter.

And in each of the splitViews a new NSView is placed. Here in this view you can put your views from a single or multiple xibs.

Check here for [ViewOnWindow](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5604837/viewonwindow?da=y) how you can show a view from another xib to your main window.

Check here for [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3XLInzZIs8).

Comment: But that doesn't split the toolbar like it does in the picture.

Comment: I dont see any toolbar here. If you are saying "Full Scan > Automatic Sca > " as toolbar. It isn't. It is a view on top of right view. Actually this window contains 4 subviews.

Comment: So is there a way to get the traffic lights to show up in subview? I'm sort of confuse how you're approaching this.

Comment: @PhongLe: No bro, that traffic lights are on the main window, and subviews are drawn on top of it. Wait I am sending you some multiple views example, if i get .

Comment: I know how to add a subview the way you did, but that only adds it to the content area. If you notice at the picture I posted, it looks like two windows on top of each other. If I were to add the second window into the first one, it would be the black window with the second window in it, instead of on it.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a custom window with the black background for the top right part of the window. Search for custom window cocoa to find examples of how to do this. I don't see the point of the custom window in this situation, you could just split the content of the window, it probable branding.

Comment: You could, but they have the left side slide and out, and I wanted to kind of copy that affect.

Comment: You can do that too, but it is a custom window still. Read up on views and windows